# IE and Chrome: css custom outline issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, focus, outline

I'm trying to create a custom outline for a button and I'm facing issues with Chrome and IE and Edge.

See this codepen: http://codepen.io/alansouzati/pen/dXEWLB

```
.custom:focus {
  outline: black solid 2px;  
}

.custom:active,
.custom:hover,
.custom:visited {
  outline: 0;
}
```

In Safari and Firefox I get the expected behavior.

To test it, click the second button (Custom focus). In IE and Edge I'm getting the outline even though I did not press tab. In Safari and Firefox the outline only shows up if I press tab, not when I click the button.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue for Chrome and IE ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .blur() in jQuery to avoid focusing after a button is clicked.

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert('hi');
}

$(".custom").click(function(e) {
  $(this).blur();
  myFunction();
});
```

```css
.custom:focus {
  outline: black solid 2px;  
}

.custom:active,
.custom:hover,
.custom:visited {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Default focus</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="button" class="custom">Custom focus</button>
```

Comment: I don't have jQuery in my project. Also it feels weird to me to remove the focus from the button

Comment: If you're not using jQuery, you can try this: 
<button type="button" onclick="this.blur();myFunction()" class="custom">Custom focus</button>
I think it is caused by the built-in focus highlighting in Chrome and IE, so you must focus out it manually.

Comment: Thanks, the problem with blur is with using tab actually. If I tab to the button, and I press enter 5 times, I would expect the button to be clicked 5 times. with this blur strategy it is only clicked once.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS can be simplified to

```
.custom:focus:not(:active) {
  outline: black solid 2px;  
}
```

And then Edge will render the outline just like Chrome, which makes me think the problem has to do with the handling of [CSS selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in Edge.

**Updated Codepen**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgvYPR

Note however that in your example when I click on the second button with the mouse and then move the cursor outside the button before releasing it, the outline appears even if the tab key was not pressed: same behavior in all browsers.
If this is not intended, I'd suggest you switch to a JavaScript solution.

Comment: This behavior is not what I'm expecting. Actually I decided to follow the instructions provided in this post: https://marcysutton.com/button-focus-hell/. Which goes along to your suggestion to use Javascript to solve the focus issue.